# streetview and map side by side

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am trying to implement this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple)  on my webforms page, slightly different. I have a map and when I change its mode to streetview, I want to show a small map on its bottom left corner that follows the streetview. The image I think is clear of what I try to achieve. [image]

When the map is initialised I do the following

```js
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: 10,
    tilt: 30,
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    },
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
    }
};    
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var smallmapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
    zoom: 15
};
smallmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("smallmap"), smallmapOptions);
```

and when the pegman is dropped I set the streetview to the little map as following

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map.getStreetView(), 'visible_changed', function () {
    if (this.getVisible()) {
        $("#smallmap").show();

        var streetViewPanorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map"), {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
            pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10
            }
        });
        smallmap.setStreetView(streetViewPanorama);           
    } else {
        $("#smallmap").hide();
    }
});
```

however I do not get the desired result as you see in this pic. My setup or way of doing this must be wrong.

[image]

edit: I also tried the following, but no difference

```js
var streetViewPanorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("map"), {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(this.position.lat(), this.position.lng()),
            pov: {
                heading: 34,
                pitch: 10
            }
        });
```

by the way, I do not understand this pov property of the above, maybe this is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the smallmapOptions code to the following and moved it inside the visible_changed event and now I see the small map clearly with the pegman walking according to the map's streetview

```
var smallmapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(this.position.lat(), this.position.lng()),
    zoom: 15
}; 
smallmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("smallmap"), smallmapOptions);
```